# Reference for Clifford theory of algebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, associative-algebras

Clifford theory relates the representation theory of a group to that of a normal subgroup.  A good reference for this is Curtis and Reiner's "Methods in Representation theory II", Theorem 11.1.

> **Theorem (Clifford theory)**
>
> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$.  Let $M$ be a simple $kG$-module and $L$ a simple $kN$-submodule of ${\rm res}^G_N(M)$. Then the following statements hold:
>
> 1. The $kN$-module ${\rm res}^G_N(M)$ is semisimple, and is isomorphic to a direct sum of conjugates of $L$.
> 2. The $kN$-homogenous components of ${\rm res}^G_N(M)$ are permuted transitively by $G$.
> 3. Let $\hat{L}$ be a $kN$-homogenous component of ${\rm res}^G_N(M)$ containing $L$, and let $\hat{N}=\{ x\in G: x \hat{L}=\hat{L} \}$.  Write $G$ as a disjoint union $G=\cup_{i=1}^n g_i \hat{N}$.  Then $\{g_iL: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ is a complete set of non-isomorphic conjugates of $L$, and each appears with equal multiplicity in ${\rm res}^G_N(M)$.

I am looking for a reference which generalises this theorem to other algebras.  In particular, to the "skew-group ring" situation where a finite group, $G$, acts by automorphisms on an algebra $A$.  We then get that Clifford theory relates the representation theories of $A$ and 
$$ A \rtimes G  =  \{ \sum_{x \in  G} a_x x : a \in A \} . $$

One possible reference for this is Ram and Rammage "Affine Hecke algebras, cyclotomic Hecke algebras and Clifford theory", however they focus on induction and restriction between $A \rtimes G $ and $A \rtimes H$ where $H$ is the inertia group of a given simple module.  I would prefer a reference to a theorem of the above form, directly relating $A \rtimes G$ and $A$, so that I can just write "please see...." without going into any more detail.  This is lazy of me, I know, but I think that such a reference should exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest [Reiten, Riedtmann: Skew group algebras in the representation theory of Artin algebras, Journal of Algebra 92, 1985] if you have that $|G|$ is invertible in $A$ and $A$ is an Artin algebra.

If not, there is also a recent preprint (which I haven't read yet): [Liping Li: Representations of Modular skew group algebras, arXiv: [1211.0333](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0333)] which may contain some results that are of interest to you.

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you very much.